# Selenium webdriver doesn't recognize this radio element. Can someone assist me?

Tags: java, selenium, radio-button, webdriver

```
<br>
<input id="workedWithGR" type="radio" onclick="showDiv('hiddenInput');" value="yes" checked="" name="workedWithGR" style="border:none;">

<label>Yes</label>

<input id="workedWithGR" type="radio" onclick="hideDiv('hiddenInput');" value="no" name="workedWithGR" style="border:0px;">
```

For yes and no buttons I keep getting "no element found error for Webdriver".  I can't do the xpath because there are quotes in the id.

Comment: Just escape the quotes with "\". Can you post a snippet of the html?

Comment: <input type="radio" onclick="hideDiv('hiddenInput');" value="no" id="workedWithGR" name="workedWithGR" style="border:0px;">

Comment: here is the xpath //*[@id="workedWithGR"]

Comment: I don't see the problem or see where the ID has quotes, "workedWithGR" is perfectly acceptable. Perhaps the problem is that the ID changes? If so fire up firebug and stick that Xpath in it does it return the element you'd expect?

Comment: its not taking the id i think because both the yes and No have the same id

Comment: //*[@id="workedWithGR"]

Comment: thats the xpath for yes

Comment: //*[@id="workedWithGR"]

Comment: Same Xpath for nNo...is there a way to find By Value??

Comment: Take a look at the answer I posted

Answer (score 2):

Use the tag "value" instead or the child node "label" then recursively go up the tree to select the right element. For instance I'm assuming your html has the following:

```
<br>
  <input id="workedWithGR" type="radio" onclick="showDiv('hiddenInput');" value="yes" checked="" name="workedWithGR" style="border:none;">
    <label>Yes</label>
  <input id="workedWithGR" type="radio" onclick="hideDiv('hiddenInput');" value="no" name="workedWithGR" style="border:0px;">
    <label>No</label>
```

So try something like the following keying off the node label:

```
//input[@id=\"workedWithGR\"]/label[text()="Yes"]/../input
```

Comment: +1, seems a reasonable solution, just another possible XPath (not going to put another answer, since this one works fine) could be: `//label[text()="Yes"]/ancestor::input[@id="workedWithGR"]` ...both will get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

I use this approach for radio input. Avoid having to look for multiple input elements / works with variable number of radio buttons having same name.

```
String valueToSelect = "no";
List<WebElement> radios = driver.findElement(By.name("workedWithGR"));
if (radios.size() == null)
    return ;

for (WebElement radio : radios){
    if (radio.getAttribute("value").equals(valueToSelect)){
        radio.click();
        break;
    }
}
```